# ios - setting a standardUserDefaults while running the simulator does not save the data

Tags: ios, ios5

I am working with the simulator, and I am doing something like this when the app starts to check if it was opened for the first time:

and then checking if that key/value is empty so that this code executes only once:

```
 NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if([standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"first_time_cookie"] == nil)
    {
        [standardUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"first_time_cookie"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
```

but every time I run the program, it executes again. Any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a bool is not an object. This should work

```
if([standardUserDefaults boolForKey:@"first_time_cookie"] == NO)
{
    [standardUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"first_time_cookie"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: I just compiled the snipped and it works well on the iOS 6 simulator.

Comment: -1 All data is stored as objects in NSUserDefaults. A BOOL is just converted to an NSNumber.

Comment: I know that all data is stored as objects in NSUserDefaults. And you don't know, that boolForKey is a convenient method that converts this object to a bool.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess: `standardUserDefaults` is nil?

Comment: There's no other bug in the code. Something else is broken in your setup.

Answer (score 1):

You can do different!

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], @"first_time_cookie"];
[defaults registerDefaults:dict];

if ([defaults boolForKey:@"first_time_cookie"] == NO){
   [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"first_time_cookie"];
   [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: thanks, what is the NSDictionary thing you are doing there? Could you explain what it does please?

Comment: Sure. You don't need to test if it's nil. That dict set the default values for your keys. If you, by any chance, change your values it won't affect your app. It's just for the first time the app runs!

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"first_time_cookie"] == false)
```

and let me know if it works,

gung-ho

Comment: It's "NO" not "false". And in a condition preferably `!` instead of `== NO`.